# Strange behavior from Oracle current_timestamp

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a scheduled process constantly update empty timestamp column with current timestamp, but interestingly I see such inconsistency:

[image]

each of the records is update by a single update to a single or multiple row:

```
update timestamp = current_timestamp where row_condition = true;
```

But how can this happened, that Oracle `current_timestamp` behaved differently in different call of the query? one output exactly the correct timestamp but the other output stuff from nowhere (the 31-DEC-69)?

Comment: What was different in the behavior? Also, do you mean you had a process running for the past almost 50 years? I don't believe that. (Or, are you saying the 31-DEC-69 is incorrect and you don't know why it got inserted?)

Comment: @mathguy you are right the question is not so clear so I update it. I don't know how `current_timestamp` gave that 31-DEC-69..

Comment: current_timestamp is a timestamp with timezone, and I guess the column is too. That implies the time zone of the session creating the record is GMT-4 (East Coast US ?) and it is being inserted with an epoch time of 1-Jan-1970.

Comment: @GaryMyers "East Coast US" -- correct :) . Could you please elaborate how did you find out and why it leads to Jan/01/1970 and why the other time stamp is fine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds as though you may have a DEFAULT value for that column. Rows were inserted where a value was not provided for the timestamp column, so it was populated with the default value.

Try `select data_default from all_tab_columns where table_name = 'YOUR_TABLE'`; YOUR_TABLE is the table name (remember to write it in uppercase). This will tell you if there is a default value for that column. You may add the column name in the where clause if you like, too - but if you don't you may find even more information you may not have been aware of.

Comment: Is there a trigger on the table?

Comment: no trigger. Oh forget to mention tomcat and Oracle are in CENTOS but the application is running in Windows, but I don't think it is the problem...